# How to get a similarity percentage?

Tags: java

I have 2 "DNA Strands". I want to find the similarity between the two strands. It has to be a percentage, and I know 16/20 will result in zero. What do I code?

```
public class JoshuaIshaanAnalyzer1
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("DNA Analyzer 1.0");

        System.out.println(" ");

        int similarity = 0;

        char [] testStrand =   {'A','T','T','A','G','A','C','A','T','G','G','A','G','T','T','A','C','C','A','T'};

        char [] targetStrand = {'A','T','A','A','G','A','C','A','A','C','G','A','G','A','T','A','C','C','A','T'};

        System.out.print("Test Strand:    ");

        for (int i=0; i<testStrand.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(testStrand[i]);
            }

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.print("Target Strand:  ");

        for (int i=0; i<targetStrand.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(targetStrand[i]);

        }


        for (int i=0; i<19; i++ )
         {
            if (testStrand[i] == targetStrand[i])
                {
                    similarity++;
                }
         }    
    }
}
```

There are 20 chars in total.

Comment: Use `float` or `double`

Comment: @kaykay how would I do that?

Comment: If you want the percentage and only use a number of elements that divides 100, just multiply by 100 *before* dividing, e.g. `(100 * 16) / 20` = 80 or simplified to `5*16`. Otherwise see kaykay's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `int` to `float` when performing the division.

```
int numerator;
int denominator;
float percentage = (numerator * 100f) / denominator;
```

The key here is to multiply be `100f`.  It will do two things:

1. Converts your expression result to `float`
2. Converts your value (0.8) into a percentage (80).